# PyQt can widget be stored in the local variable?

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
class App(QMainWindow):


def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()


def initUI(self):

    label = QLabel('Python', self)
    label.move(50,50)
    self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

in the initUI() function :

the label widget is coded as `label = QLabel('python',self)`
but when the initUI() function finish and exit, the label variable will be discarded and the label object will be deleted.

so why it isn't coded like

```
self.lable = QLabel('python',self)
```

and why that kind of form is also correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing `label = QLabel('Python', self)` is equivalent to `label = QLabel('Python', parent=self)`. When you specify a parent, a reference to `label` gets stored in `parent` implicitly and the reference count for `label` is incremented. If you are unfamiliar with reference counting - a variable will only be removed by the garbage collector when its reference count has been reduced to 0. So in your example `label` doesn't actually get deleted (if you had instead written `label = QLabel('Python')` your claim would hold).

Similarly, when you write `self.label = QLabel('python', self)` you are instructing python to store a reference in `self` and incrementing the reference count once again.

In both cases, by storing a reference to `label` inside another object that exists outside of the scope in which `label` is created, you enable to `label` to persist for the lifetime of that object.

As for which to use, they are both correct, but you may choose one or the other depending on what you are trying to do. For simple things like static labels the second method provides no benefits and increases the amount of typing you have to do. However for more complex applications storing a reference in `self` gives you an easy way to access the object from elsewhere in the code.